# searching mysql database using phrases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this local classifieds site with a mysql database and am using PHP.
it has a table where listings are stored but we are going to be using just 3 columns for search :

columns
title  , description , price

what is the best way to search the database when a user types in a phrase e.g 
"fairly used mobile devices 20,000"

i want to be able to search the 3 columns if the phrases match any in the database efficiently. I know about the '%LIKE' feature but i think there should be a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with `%LIKE%`, also in which direction a better way, maybe if you explain why are you not ok with %LIKE% and what you want more to achieve, we might help

Comment: well i hope the search result should check for every single word or phrase in the columns and return appropriate results. but %like does not do that

Comment: I am not aware if there's a function in mysql which can split it, but you can do it in PHP, I will try to format an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use like,

define fulltext index on your 3 columns

and search as fulltext

Answer (score 1):

You should `explode()` the string to search for each word. On the other hand you have to set proper column type for `price` because `20,000` is not a valid numeric type, you need either to store 20.000 in the db and cast in php 20,000 to 20.000, or explode the strings by `,` also, not only by free space.

A simple explode can be done with splitting the string by a `' '` - free space and it will work for your variation, but it will not work if the user type `fairly, used` because `LIKE '%fairly,%' will not return the desired output.

I will show a simple code for exploding by empty string, just for explaining the logic, but I hope you can make the search engine a little bit smarter by replacing undesired characters later.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="phrase" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$phrases = isset($_POST['phrase']) ? $_POST['phrase'] : null;
$phrases = explode(' ', $phrases);
foreach ($phrases as $phrase) {
    $queries[] = $db->query("SELECT title, description, price 
                            FROM test 
                            WHERE title LIKE '%$phrase%'
                            OR description LIKE '%$phrase%'
                            OR price LIKE '%$phrase%';
    ");
}
// managing the output should be done depending on the db library you are using
```

Comment: thanks but i just discovered fulltext, i think it would work for me, thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

you can try it as:

```
$search = 'fairly used mobile devices 20,000';

list_title like '%".implode('%', explode(' ', $search))."%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$search = 'fairly used mobile devices 20,000';

SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE column_title like '%$search%' 
OR description like '%$search%'
OR price like '%$search%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `column_title` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 0
              WHEN `description` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1
              WHEN `price` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 2
              ELSE 3
         END
```

If you want to search each word, You have to split the string with space and add those also in query